# What is the procedure for removing an AMD Athlon XP 2200+ CPU from the motherboard?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I am trying to replace the CPU in this computer. Can anyone step me through the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you need a flat headed scredriver and thers a little opening on the metal flange where you put it in. once the flathead is in there you push down and pry away the flange from the heatsink. thats how you do it with most amd processors.

After that thers a small lever next to the socket wich you push off to the side and then lift up that unlocks the pins from the cpu and then you should just be able to lift off the cpu.

Also, if you ever have some problems removing it from the heat sink, please read this Superuser thread:

[How to unglue microprocessor from heat sink?](https://superuser.com/questions/108518/how-to-unglue-microprocessor-from-heat-sink)