# How do I safely separate the heatsink/pipe from the processor on the Packard Bell F7280?

Tags: cpu, shutdown, overheating, heatsink, thermal-paste

My laptop shuts down and the main fan stops. I am convinced it's dust build up in a void below the heat-sink fins but the heatsink is firmly stuck to the processor. (see link to manual page 8 )

ftp://ftp.packardbell.com/pub/itemnr/7022260000/easynotef_disassembly%20manual.pdf

As you can see a step seems to be missing between step 1 and step 2

Step 1
Shows Fig 6 (nothing removed just what screws to remove and socket to unclip)

Step 2
Shows Fig 7 suddenly lifting off the heatsink and exposing the CPU.

Does anyone know the missing step ?

I've read that dental floss slid side to side plus a gentle twist of the heat-sink separates it from the CPU without damaging either. Both surfaces can then be cleaned.

[How to unglue microprocessor from heat sink?](https://superuser.com/questions/108518/how-to-unglue-microprocessor-from-heat-sink)

So can anyone confirm this is the here from the photos ?